# SNMP implementation unreliable

Tags: snmp

For fun I'm adding an SNMP server to the IP-stack I wrote ([MyIP](https://github.com/folkertvanheusden/MyIP)).

This somewhat works: on a local LAN, I can do a 'walk' (using getnext - no bulk as that is not implemented) without any problems.
Over the internet though it often times out after the first exchange (getnext + response), OR completely fails, or works fine - it never fails after e.g. 2 getnext requests. It has been tried on several locations (vps's and isp's).

When I run tcpdump on my firewall, I see packets come in. When I capture them with wireshark, then wireshark says all is fine.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with these SNMP packets? [example network trace](https://vanheusden.com/permshare/test3.pcap)

Comment: No response for 10 days. That is normal. You show 6 GETNEXT requests that have a response. What is that supposed to contribute? The problem could be anywhere in your code, or even system or network config (firewall, etc).

Comment: @GambitSupport isn't that true for any question...?

Anyway: I found that if I connect my laptop directly to the fritzbox (modem between internet and lan), that then the walk works fine. Only with the linux-router in between the walk stalls after a few getnexts. Both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Found the problem: it was a padding problem. Before I padded on UDP level, not on Ethernet-level.